# How to use zip function to associate column number with value of excel cell using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm creating a dictionary where the keys should be the row number and the values of the dictionary should be a list of column numbers with the order being determined by the values of that row, sorted in descending order.

My code below is:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

vWB = load_workbook(filename="voting.xlsx")
vSheet = vWB.active

d = {}
for idx, row in enumerate(vSheet.values, start=1):
    row = sorted(row, reverse=True)
    d[idx] = row
```

output:

{1: [0.758968208500514, 0.434362232763003, 0.296177589742431, 0.0330331941352554], 2: [0.770423104229537, 0.770423104229537, 0.559322784244604, 0.455791535747786] etc..}

What I want:

{1: [4,2,1,3], 2: [3,4,1,2], etc..}

I've been trying to create a number to represent the column number of each value

```
genKey = [i for i in range(values.max_column)
```

And then using the zip function to associate the column number with each value

```
dict(zip(column key list, values list)
```

So I have a dict with columns as keys 1,2,n and values as values and then I can sort the keys in Descending order and I can iterate over row and zip again with the key being the row number.

**I'm unsure how to use this zip function and get to my desired endpoint. Any help is welcomed.**

Comment: `row[0]` is the first cell in the row, not the row number. This can be obtained from any cell object but in the case enumerate would be easier.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be simple, I'm new to python!

Comment: When you're learning Python start with simpler statements. Here, nested loops would be easier to understand and change than comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `enumerate`:

```
dictionary = {
    row_id: [cell.value for cell in row]
    for row_id, row in enumerate(vSheet.rows)
}
```

`enumerate` can be applied to iterables and returns an iterator over a tuple of index and value. For example:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(list(enumerate(x)))
```

yields `[("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 2)]`.

If you want to start with 1, then use `enumerate(x, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
dictionary = {
    i: [cell.value for cell in row[0:]]
    for i, row in enumerate(vSheet.rows)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the cell values this is easy:

```
d = {}
for idx, row in enumerate(ws.values, start=1):
   row_s = sorted(row) # created a sorted copy for comparison
   d[idx] = [row_s.index(v) + 1 for v in row]
```

Comment: Thank you yes this is what I was looking for I just need the values in descending order so have added reverse=TRUE.

Comment: is there a way to convert the values of the sorted dictionary into column numbers e.g largest value is found in column 3 so the dictionary reads 1: [3, etc.]?

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: I want my final dictionary to have keys representing the row number e.g 1,2.. n and the values being the column number that the values of each row appear in descending order. E.g final dict will be {1: [4,2,3,1] etc..}. key 1 represents row 1 and the values represent the columns that the values appear in descending order. Is there a way to do this by generating the numbers to represent the column number and then zip with the value using dict(zip(column key list, values list) and then iterating over the row and using zip again with the key for the row number.

Comment: Please edit your question above, not the comment.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: So you want the order of the columns before sorting to be reported?

Comment: I want the order of the columns after sorting

Comment: That doesn't make much sense because it will be 1,2,3,4,….